# How to send logs generated within code to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-iot-greengrass

I am trying to send the logs (being generated as a part of my on-premise device and the message being sent or received using devices onboarded on greengrass) to AWS.

How is it possible?

I wanted to check SDKs also but found no documentation stating how to do it online.

Comment: Here is one way: [Collecting Metrics and Logs from Amazon EC2 Instances and On-Premises Servers with the CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html).

Comment: That probably assumes you are already writing to log files on local disk or similar. Is that true for you? Or do you not have any logging yet?

Comment: @srk I am not writing to an log files. Azure offers Application Insights which can be used to publish console.log statements to the cloud directly using the Application Insights lib for the code language. Is it possible to do something like that with AWS ? With least additional memory being occupied as I will be using edge devices.

Comment: What language/framework are you using?

Comment: @srk as of now I am not bound by any language. I can pick any language or framework

Comment: I am able to get connection logs for Aws IoT using cloudwatch . However, I want to print code level messages for debugging or messages being exchanges using Matt to cloudwatch. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a logging framework or some other abstraction so your code is not tightly coupled to AWS CloudWatch. Then you can easily change the log destination (CloudWatch, file, database) without changing your code.

For example, let's say you're using .NET. [Here](https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet) is how you can configure popular .NET logging frameworks to send logs to CloudWatch. Or [here](https://github.com/kislyuk/watchtower) is a solution for Python. I'm sure there are similar solutions in other languages/frameworks.

If you are already generating log files, another option is to use the [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) to send those existing logs to CloudWatch.

Comment: This approach works for me. Are you aware if its available for python.

Comment: Added a link for Python to my answer. Have you done any research? Where are you stuck in your research? All of these links are from straightforward Google searches like "python send logs to cloudwatch"...

Comment: I was trying to implement sending code logs to cloudwatch using IAM policies. So all my research was into that direction.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send logs to Cloudwatch just use Cloudwatch agentю [Install Cloudwatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)

You can send logs to Elasticsearch using logstash as well.